# bulk delete from two related tables performance

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-performance

I have two tables structured as below: (multiple ai_$object tables for each object type in the system)

```
       ai_$object         ,       ai_ext_ids
--------------------        -------------------------- 
ext_id | hash                    id | ext_id | object_name | sfID
```

from bulk deletion I got sf_ids, and need to delete records from those two tables,
the dummiest way of this deletion would be like this:

in pseudocode-->

```
$idToBeDeleted = SELECT ext_id FROM ai_tr_tbl_extids WHERE objectName='$object' AND sfID ='$s'" ;

DELETE FROM ai_tr_tbl_extids WHERE objectName='$object' AND sfID ='$s';

DELETE FROM ai_$object WHERE ext_id='$idToBeDeleted';
```

My question is how to improve performance of this part? And this code runs with in loop, should I do this deletion with bulk deletion with arrays: SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,4)

Comment: Set up foreign key constraints that allow DELETE CASCADE?

Comment: @MarkBaker I am not expert in db operations. Did you see that ai_$object is dynamic table name, object_name of ai_ext_ids corresponds to that table name.  I am not sure this can be done with delete cascade?

Answer (score 0):

The objectName column should be indexed for better performance.  And try the following queries.

```
$idToBeDeleted = SELECT ext_id FROM ai_tr_tbl_extids WHERE objectName='$object' AND sfID ='$s'" ;

DELETE FROM ai_tr_tbl_extids WHERE ext_id='$idToBeDeleted';

DELETE FROM ai_$object WHERE ext_id='$idToBeDeleted';
```

But if you will be able to get the list of `ext_id` to be deleted, you can remove the loop and just delete with `IN`.

```
DELETE FROM ai_tr_tbl_extids WHERE ext_id IN ($idToBeDeletedCommaSeparatedValue');

DELETE FROM ai_$object WHERE ext_id IN ($idToBeDeletedCommaSeparatedValue');
```